# An problem of ideal splitting in number field extension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

If $L/K$ is Galois extension of number field, $\mathfrak{p}$ is an prime integral ideal of $K$. One would asserts that:

$\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_L=\mathfrak{P}_1^{e_1}\dots\mathfrak{P}_g^{e_g}$.

with $e_i$ all equal, residual field of $\mathfrak{P}_1$ all isomorphic.

But one could construct an example like that: take $K=\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathfrak{p}=(5)$ consider $f(x)=(x+1)(x^2+2)+5x$, which being irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ but reducible over $\mathbb{F}_5$. Consider field extension $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f(x))$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. $\mathfrak{p}$ should decompose to two ideal with residual field $\mathbb{F}_5$ and $\mathbb{F}_{25}$ respectively. What's wrong with my argument?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f(x))$ is not a Galois extension over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @user72870 Thanks for comments, you're right, adjoining all roots fix the problem